# HTML5 Audio currentTime property is not always the same

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have an Audio element, with a random source, from wikipedia, I attach a listener to the timeupdate, and I put a console.log(this.currentTime) on it, and I always get different values, can somebody explain me that.

HTML:

```
<audio id="track" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg" controls preload="auto">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var track = document.getElementById('track');

  track.ontimeupdate = function(){
    console.log(this.currentTime);
  };
};
```

Result:

```
0
0.241375
0.492853
0.743976 
0.995482
```

Again:

```
0.241815
0.49318
0.744024
0.995427
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The currentTime property sets or returns the current position (in seconds) of the audio/video playback.

**In your case**
You subscribe to the event, ontimeupdate which in turn fires when the audio/video is being played. I.E your moving the elapsed time of the track by playing or fast forwarding.

```
 this.currentTime
```

**Will just give you how many seconds it have played/elapsed.**

When **setting this property**, the playback will jump to the specified position.
When **returning this property**, it will give you in "seconds" how long the audio/video have played.
**Example**

**To set**

```
audioTrack.currentTime="theAmountOfSecondsThatHaveElapsed"

audioTrack=document.getElementById("track");
audioTrack.currentTime=5; //sets audioTrack to five seconds
```

**To return**
    audioTrack.currentTime

```
audioTrack=document.getElementById("track");
var audiotrackPosition = audioTrack.currentTime; //returns audioTrack
```

Code example

```
function timelineEvent(start, stop, name)
{
     this.start = start;
     this.stop = stop;
     this.name = name;
}

var eventArr = new Array();
eventArr.push(new timelineEvent(10,20, "Drums starting"));
eventArr.push(new timelineEvent(25,27,"Pitch goes down"));

for(var i = 0; i < eventArr.length; i++)
{

     console.log("Event -- " + eventArr[i].name + " --");
     console.log("Event starts @ " + eventArr[i].start);
     console.log("Event stops @ " + eventArr[i].stop);  
}
```

Another solution to you might be to use if you want to manipulate the numbers it gives you!

```
math.floor(audioTrack.currentTime);
```

Comment: I understand you explanation, but nevertheless the currentTime propery is always different, for me thats incorrect because it should always give you the same numbers, even with the decimals.

Comment: @daver can explain why you ned something else? What are you tryingto Solve?!

Comment: I need to develop a timeline for an audio project, and I need to store  elements on a position, so I'm using an array with the currentTime as the index, but because the propery is always different I can't get the stored item when I read the property again.

Comment: @daver Okay I think I understand, but this timeline of yours. You can set an interval instead. A timeline always has a start and stop, and if you want to place things on a time line create an array fill it with objects that holds the start and stop. Say something happened, on the 21:second and then stops on the 24:second. You could create an object holding many of the object with just two properties start: time when event starts, stop: time when event stops. That way you could have an array filled with objects that tells you the start and stop time for your event.

Comment: Hi, I get your answer but I need more precise time, that includes the miliseconds